# How get all two array values using select query at once

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to get Name and corresponding Score at the latest time. So I tried:

```
    $queryObj = mysql_query("SELECT `Name`,`Score` from `Table`.`Score` where `Date` = (    SELECT max(`Date`)    from `Table`.`Score`) and `Name`<>'' ");
```

then get value from it by:

```
  while( $obj = mysql_fetch_object( $queryObj ) )  {
  $data = array();
  $data['Name'] = $obj->Name;
  $data['Score'] = $obj->Score;
  $searches[] = $data;
  }
```

But when I print :

```
    print_r(array_values($searches));
```

the first value is missing in the array, so that won't be the right way.
I also tried:

```
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryObj);
    for ($i = 0; $i <3; $i++)
    print( $row['Name'][$i]." Score: ".$row['Score'][$i]."<br />\n");
```

But it won't give me the right results also. How do I get the value from that query? (the query is correct, I tested it). Any body has suggestion ?

Edit: I add my sample data here:

```
Name   Score      Date
abc     3   2013-08-29 10:11:47
abc     2   2013-08-29 09:39:23
abc     1   2013-08-28 10:22:28
jane    2   2013-08-29 09:39:23
        2013-08-29 10:08:36
jane    1   2013-08-29 10:11:47
tarzan  1   2013-08-29 10:11:47
```

Note: Yes, there is some blank values.

My expected result would be:

```
abc score 3
jane score 1
tarzan score 1
```

Comment: what do you mean by first value? are you sure that the query returned valid result? did you tested using PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not the matter of query result? (did you tried to execute it in mysql?). Also, do not use `mysql_*` functions - they are deprecated

Comment: Yes, I am very sure that it is right query. I tested that sql in phpmyadmin and it returns me two columns, 3 rows of results.

Comment: Please, show sample data from your tables. It's impossible to say, why it is missing now.

Comment: You need to read the mysql documentation before asking questions.

Comment: I added sample data as requested. @Virus: Yes, I do some google research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after you have updated your question and provided what you expect, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t1.Score 
FROM Table.Score t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT max(Date) MaxDate, Name, Score
    FROM Table.Score
            WHERE Name <> ''
    GROUP BY Name
) t2
    ON t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.Date = t2.MaxDate
```

This will give you pairs of `Name` and `Score` for **each** `Name` with `Score` based on his latest `Date` (1 row per `Name`).

So replace your original query with mine in this line:

```
$queryObj = mysql_query(" ... ");
```

Then:

```
$rows = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryObj)) {
    $rows[$row['Name']] = $row['Score'];
}
```

And you can nicely `foreach` it in the exact way you wanted in your last comment:

```
foreach($rows as $name => $score) {
    echo $name . ' - ' . $score . "\n";
}
```

Comment: No, sorry, that is not my wish. I want to get all the rows and be able to print its values. Like in the post edited.

Comment: Yes, now when you edited question and shown expected results, i can see what you are after, i'll provide the solution soon, will edit my answer.

Comment: How do I put them into variable in my php then print out ?

Comment: Just replace your query `SELECT Name...` with mine provided in edit, do `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryObj);` and then `var_dump($row);`

Comment: it's an array. I still have no idea can I print it in php ? Actually I don't have problem with my query but I have problem with how to fed that result from query to php variable and print out. Using your query in phpmyadmin I get one extra row, which I think is not very precise.

Comment: Your query is wrong and you can see it in your own example - for "abc" you should have score "1" from latest date and it shows score "3" - your query will always show first row for person, cause it's not connecting dates in any way. Mine was showing one more result, cause it was missing `WHERE Name <> ''` which i already corrected in my answear. Since we are getting more results now i also edited the way to get them into PHP array - added `while...`, so after running this code you will have everything in `$rows` variable.

Comment: The latest date score will be "3", both your and mine query is true and give same result Bro ! Using printing method you give, I can't get the value nicely from the array. How to use something like this: foreach ($rows as $name => $score) {
echo "$name = $score\n";
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36459/discussion-between-user1314404-and-michal-prajsnar)

Comment: Actually the query part of mine is correct. When I add newer record and newer date time, look like your query also include the old result, but mine works well. So I update this comment for other user reference. Your extracting value from query and printing part still correct and answered my question so I still choose that to be my answer. Thanks !